# open a file and get the content in an array

Tags: php, file

In php how to get a file by his path and return his content in an array?
lets say that I have file: file.txt that have the path:path_file, and the file is TSV like this:

```
a0 b0
a1 b1
a2 b2
...
```

how can I access the file and put his content in an array like this:

```
array(
array(a0,b0),
array(a1,b1),
array(a2,b2),
 )
```

How can I get the file content by the use of the path?

```
 function get_content_file($path_file)
 {
 $data[];
  //open file by path
  //read file content
  //push the content in an array
  return $data;
 }
```

Comment: I would suggest looking into [`file()`](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and [`array_map()`](http://uk1.php.net/array_map) with a custom function interfacing [`explode()`](http://uk3.php.net/explode)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already get a file into an array line-by-line with [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). If you want each item in the array to be an array itself then use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to process the lines:

```
$data = file($path_file);
$data = array_map(function($l) { return explode(" ", $l); }, $data);
```

If the file's format is not "values separated by a single space" then this code won't work correctly; in that case use an appropriate split function (perhaps `preg_split`) to break up each line into tokens.

Comment: I finished my comment and it turned into a completed answer! Nice one =)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: Parallel thought processes :)

Comment: Indeed! FYI, about your line at the end about the separation, the OP uses the term `TSV` so I'm guessing explode needs to use `\t`

Comment: I didnt understood why should I use / and I didnt understood too why ppl put -1 to some questions, I tried but I found a problem...

Comment: @user1987 I would imagine the downvote is because you haven't shown your attempt at a solution. Posts should show your attempted solutions and what has gone wrong - users then help you with that. Showing no attempt at the problem isn't taken very kindly here.

Comment: it is a one line code this is why I didnt put my code..I though in such an example the idea will be enough. any way big thx for the help :)